# Fill the form with the HTTP response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, get

This is the HTML form of a hospital, of which the fields has to be filled using an API GET call when the page is loaded. 
[image]
I am using HTML, Javascript, AngularJS, and my API is coded in java.

I could fill all the input fields via GET request API, except the `select`.
My problem is in `select` the option in the form based on the API response . There are 4 select tags in the form, which are co-related.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name of Hospital</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="hospital.name" required="true">
        <!-- <p class="help-block">Name of the hospital</p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="hospital.address" id="address"></textarea>
        <!-- <p class="help-block">Address of the hospital</p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="countries"  onchange="countries(this.value)" ng-model="hospital.countryItemSelected">
                        <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>State</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="states"  onchange="states(this.value)" ng-model="hospital.stateItemSelected">
                        <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="cities"  onchange="cities(this.value)" ng-model="hospital.cityItemSelected">
                        <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city.id}}">{{city.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Locality</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="localities"  onchange="localities(this.value)" ng-model="hospital.localityItemSelected">
                        <option ng-repeat="locality in localities" value="{{locality.id}}">{{locality.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-6">      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>PIN</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pin" ng-model="hospital.pin">
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-6">      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>General Timings</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="generalTimings" ng-model="hospital.timings">
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-12">     
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Website</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" ng-model="hospital.website">
                    <!-- <textarea class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea> -->
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-12">     
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email ID</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailID" required="true" ng-model="hospital.emial">
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-6">      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mobile No.</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" required="true" ng-model="hospital.mobile">
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-6">      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone No.</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" ng-model="hospital.phone">
                </div>
        </div>  

    </div>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="formSubmit" disabled>Save</button>
```

Country options is loaded during page load, via API call, he gets respective states of that country. By choosing a state, he gets the respective cities, and same with the locality. Again this happens via API call.

This is the API call which is made to get the result.
All other input fields are filled, except the `select` ones.

[image]

```
            hospital.countryItemSelected  = response.data.success_Result.hospital.country;
            hospital.stateItemSelected  = response.data.success_Result.hospital.state;
            hospital.cityItemSelected  = response.data.success_Result.hospital.city;
            hospital.localityItemSelected  = response.data.success_Result.hospital.locality;
```

I get the names of country, state, city, locality in this result. 
On load of page, the select options with respect to these result has to be selected, with all other fields.

The names of each select field is stored in different tables.

How to solve this problem of selecting the items ?? Is there a need to get the ID's of these names to solve this problem ??

There is an option to edit the the details in the form as well. So, the select options are loaded via GET APIs.

Comment: What framework are you using?
What happens with 'hospital'

Im guessing you problem is somewhere in the co-relation with the fields. When they are filled based upon the pre select, they need to be filled to be selected.

Or its something with how the select value is rendered. Do you know what value your are getting from the API? Does it match te options of the values of your selects?

Comment: Show us the HTML template. I assume you are using ng-model for form fields. If that is case you can easily bind the `response` data to ng-model of corresponding form field

Comment: @GangadharJannu I have updated my question. Please go through it.

Comment: @HerrWalter On load of the page, I need the details of hospital to be filled. No field should be empty, including **country**, **state** (with respect to country), **city** (with respect to state) and **locality**. I know the values what I am getting via API call. Initially state, city and locality fields are disabled. Once the user selects a country, the state will be enabled, and state options are got via API call with respect to that country. Once the state is selected, city options is enabled and filled with names with respect to that state. Same with locality.